# iOS seating plan layout

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an iOS app with a seating plan layout.

Trying to use an object-oriented approach, I created a class for `TableLayoutObjects` as they have different properties.

And to lay these `TableLayoutObjects` out on the screen I am representing them as `UIButtons` that are created as I loop through the array of `TableLayoutObjects`.

```
- (void) loadTables
{
  for (TableLayoutObjects *layoutObjs in arrTableLayoutObjects)
  {
    if ([layoutObjs.shape isEqualToString:@"r"]) {
        // rectangle
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        ......

        if(layoutObjs.isInteractable) {
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tableTouchedDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tableTouchedUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
    } else {
        // text only. use label
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(layoutObjs.posX, layoutObjs.posY, layoutObjs.width, layoutObjs.height)];
        ......
    }
  }
}
```

My event handlers look like the below for now.

```
// reverts back to original color and perform other instructions
- (void) tableTouchedUpInside:(UIButton *) button
{
    button.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:.5f].CGColor;
}
```

**My question is: how do I identify the `UIButtons` to their `TableLayoutObjects`?** In the event handler after I change the colour of the button, I will also want to get or set some properties of the selected `TableLayoutObjects`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `tag` of the button to the index into the `arrTableLayoutObjects` array of the associated item.

Alternatively, create a custom class which takes the table as a parameter and is the target of the button. This object now has direct access to the button and the table item.

Comment: meaning I set `button.tag = ??` inside the for loop? How do I get the current index in a `for(... in ...)` loop? or should I change it to a `for(;;)` kind of loop?

Comment: You can change the loop, or use a counter

Comment: Thanks~ I seem to understand the former suggestion better and want to try that out. I see that `tag` is described as a `An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application.` Will that give any conflicts with other tags in the application?

Comment: Only if you are using tags anywhere else, which I guess you aren't

Comment: hahah yeah I am not using it now. but now that I learn the power of it and want to use it in other parts of the app in future, what should I look out for? does it mean other buttons in other views should not have the same tag numbering?

Comment: Only if you wanted to use `viewWithTag:` to search for views. The custom class option is the 'correct' solution rather than using tags.

Answer (score 2):

I think your example is a perfect fit for implementing a **[`UICollectionView`](http://nshipster.com/uicollectionview/)**. Solution with the buttons is less clean and more complex.

Comment: yes that was one option I was exploring. but then because my tables are not laid out in an orderly manner (unlike classrooms or cinemas for example), I had problems trying to put the tables in their correct places.